sembler vs paraitre
Sembler and paraitre both mean "to seem". But what is the difference between them?
According to Collins Dictionary:
Ça paraît incroyable. It seems incredible.
Le temps semble s’améliorer. The weather seems to be improving.
Ça semble incroyable and Ça paraît incroyable aren't the same thing?

If we consider the etymology sembler is close to avoir l'air ("appear"), donner l'impression (give the impression") whereas paraitre is closer to être visible ("be visible"), se montrer ("show oneself").
When using sembler, I give a subjective description, it is a personal opinion, for all I know I might be wrong.
When using paraitre my expression is more neutral, I just describe what I see.
To illustrate this I'll give the examples given in Larousse :

Paraître / sembler : employé avec un adjectif, paraître décrit de manière neutre l'aspect, l'apparence : il paraît jeune (et il l'est, pour autant qu'on sache). Sembler laisse entendre que la réalité pourrait ne pas correspondre à l'apparence : il semble jeune (mais peut-être est-il plus vieux qu'il ne paraît).

Il parait jeune. → He looks young.
Il semble jeune. → He seems/appears young.
If talking about someone's voice (I heard over the phone), someone I haven't seen, I would say:
Il avait l'air jeune → He sounded young.
Il semblait jeune → He seemed young.
But I will not say this difference is always as clear cut, and much depends on the context.
I suppose that le temps semble s’améliorer could be translated as "it looks as if the weather's improving".
Let's imagine the following conversations between two people:

-J'ai gagné dix mille euros au loto.
-Ça parait incroyable. (I believe what I'm being told)


-J'ai gagné dix mille euros au loto.
-Ça semble incroyable. (There might be a hint of a doubt in my voice)

Note that English

Mais dans certains cas, c'est équivalent, et on peut ingerchanger les deux sans vraiment faire attention à la nuance.

C'est ce que je sous-entends dans la phrase "But I will not say this difference is always as clear cut, and much depends on the context.". C'est le problème des dictionnaires qui ne donnent que peu d'exemples, on trouve toujours des contextes qui sont en dehors de leurs données. Par curiosité j'ai regardé après coup ce que disait le Harrap's standard et il y a bien autre chose que seem pour paraitre et sembler.

Oui, avec ce genre de question, j'ai toujours peur que celui qui pose la question cherche des distinctions claires et nettes pour les ériger en "règles" alors que la réalité est souvent plus souple.

@Frank Un mot - quand il ne définit pas un objet concret (et encore !) c'est une définition de base + un contexte.

Ou bien tu peux dire que le(s) sens d'un mot émerge(nt) des relations qu'il entretient avec les autres mots. Il y a (eu) beaucoup de théorie dans ce sens ;-)
